# Entering command-line window from quickfix window opened by YCM results in inconsistent Vim state

Tags: command-line, quickfix, plugin-you-complete-me, command-line-window

I think I'm supposed to file a bug report, however I'm not sure if for Vim or for YCM, so I'm asking this question to better understand what is really happening.

YCM has the `:YcmCompleter GoToReferences` command, which results in a quickfix window of alternative targets (if there's more than one target, clearly). I say quickfix because if I `:ls` while in it, the buffer is listed as

```
  1  a   "uffa.cpp"                     line 0
  2 %a-  "[Quickfix List]"              line 1
```

Now, while I'm in that window, I can, for instance, search via <kbd>/</kbd>. Fine. But what if I need to write a more complex search into it? I'd do <kbd>q</kbd><kbd>/</kbd>. However that results in the quickfix window being hidden in favour of the command line window. At this point `:ls` shows

```
  1  a   "uffa.cpp"                     line 0
  2 #h-  "[Quickfix List]"              line 2
 19 %a   "[Command Line]"               line 51
```

and I'm already not sure whether Vim or YCM has made the mistake. Or if just that's how things should go. However, the tricky part comes now: if I press enter on one of the search patterns, I get `E199: Active window or buffer deleted` for a brief moment, and afterwards

- the command line window keeps behaving as a buffer where I can edit stuff,
- but hitting enter just moves me to the next line,
- and hitting <kbd>Ctrl-w</kbd><kbd>k</kbd> successfully moves me away from it, which shouldn't happen,
- closing it with `:q` is successfull, but everytime I re-enter it via <kbd>q</kbd><kbd>/</kbd> I get the `E199` above, even though now <kbd>Enter</kbd> does work.

So I think at least we can be sure that the worflow, as invalid as it can be, is able to leave Vim in a non-consistent state, which I think is a bug. Now the question is whether this is a pure Vim bug, or YCM is not doing things cleanly.

I hope the following clarifies what happens:
[image: asciicast]

Comment: This does seem like a bug. `q/` shouldn't hide the qflist. In neovim, it works as you'd expect. But I'm using neither vim nor ycm, so I can't confirm where the bug is coming from. You should open a qflist normally (do a `:grep 'pattern'` or `:make`) and do `q/` and see if the bug is reproducible in vim w/o ycm. If yes, then it's a vim bug. If not, then ycm bug.

Comment: It seems to be the latter case. [I've filed it](https://github.com/ycm-core/YouCompleteMe/issues/4061).